# Create a second Replica set on same 3 nodes as another Replica set

Tags: mongodb

Can a second 3 node Replica set be installed on the same 3 nodes with another 3 node Replica set without interference?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for testing and development. Not for production, obviously. Note below, the different port numbers and data paths for each mongod instance.

If you had the first replica set like this:

```
mkdir -p /srv/mongodb/rs0-0 /srv/mongodb/rs0-1 /srv/mongodb/rs0-2

mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs0-0 --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --fork

mongod --port 27018 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs0-1 --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --fork

mongod --port 27019 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs0-2 --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --fork
```

You could add a second replica set like this to the same localhost with the following:

```
mkdir -p /srv/mongodb/rs1-0 /srv/mongodb/rs1-1 /srv/mongodb/rs1-2

mongod --port 37017 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs1-0 --replSet rs1 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --fork

mongod --port 37018 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs1-1 --replSet rs1 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --fork

mongod --port 37019 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs1-2 --replSet rs1 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --fork
```

Reference: [Deploy a Replica Set for Testing and Development](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/)